# Graph api GET group/planner/plan fails because of permission. This flow used to work lately. Any change happenned on this?

Tags: permissions, microsoft-graph-api, runtime-error

I have a Flow that retrieves a Token then uses it to perform Graph calls to groups API with the HTTP Premium connector.

I have a successful call to :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/859[...]/owners
```

This shows my token is valid and has the permissions needed for this call.

Then I have a failing call to :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/859[...]/planner/plans
```

> You do not have the required permissions to access this item.

According to MS doc, the permission needed are :

> /owners : Delegated (work or school account)  Group.Read.All and
> User.ReadBasic.All, Group.Read.All and User.Read.All, Group.Read.All
> and User.ReadWrite.All, Group.Read.All and User.Read.All and
> Application.Read.All

> /plans  : Delegated (work or school account)  Group.Read.All,
> Group.ReadWrite.All

Here is the permissions from the token I retrieve in my Flow :

> "scope": "ChannelMember.ReadWrite.All Group.ReadWrite.All
> GroupMember.ReadWrite.All User.Read User.Read.All"

All of those permission has been granted in the Sharepoint admin console.

Any idea of what is going wrong here ?

Comment: Could you please share the requestid and timestamp and the whole error message for the request failed?

Answer (score 1):

The likely issue is that you are an owner of the group, but not a member (these are two separate collections of people). Currently Planner data for a Group can only be accessed by members. If you are an owner, you can also add yourself as a member to gain access.

Comment: If this does not solve the problem, please provide the correlation id from the response of the failed request, so we can look up the actual issue.